# Automatically Propagating Changes from Parent to Dependent custom NuGet packages using TeamCity

Tags: c#, nuget, teamcity, devops

My company uses the built in TeamCity NuGet repo to create custom NuGet packages that often depend on each other. When I, say, update a .cs page in a custom parent package I'd like for those changes to propagate to all of our packages that are dependent packages of the parent - I believe I can accomplish this using a NuGet installer to "update packages".

My fear is that while I know I can force this update upon all our packages, I want to find a way to exclude anything that isn't hosted on our company repo (which should also mean anything that is hosted on the NuGet.org repo), so anything that we are using from an outside source isn't lumped into this NuGet update.

Preferably, I'd like to know if there's a way to handle this in the our .nuspec for each of our packages (though it seems wildcards don't accomplish this). Any insight to my problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it sounds a bit like you're trying to re-create the project reference experience with NuGet packages. If it's at all reasonable to do so, perhaps your best option would be to have all projects in a single solution and use project references instead.

If you're able to migrate your projects to SDK style projects (used by .NET Core, but you can still target the .NET Framework), then you can use `dotnet list package` or the `dotnet-outdated` tool. `dotnet list package --outdated` has an option to specify a list of sources to use. Perhaps if you only specify your private feed it may only search that one. Otherwise the script you create to do all this will need to overwrite the `nuget.config` file to remove other sources (like nuget.org) when running the command to get your desired output. Then you parse the output and when it finds an update, it modifies the relevant file(s).